# Read-only condition not working

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm developing an Oracle Application express (APEX 4.2) application.

One of the page controls (text box, `title`) have a "PL/SQL Expression" read-only condition:
`:APP_PROJECT_READ_ONLY = 'YES'`

`:APP_PROJECT_READ_ONLY` is an application item and it's set from a dynamic action `on_load` which fires on page load:

```
DECLARE
  CURR_USER VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  IF :REQUEST = 'NEW' THEN
    :APP_PROJECT_ID := 0;
    :APP_PROJECT_READ_ONLY := 'NO';
  ELSE
    :APP_PROJECT_ID := :P2_ID;
    SELECT OWNER  INTO CURR_USER 
    FROM PROJECTS
    WHERE ID = :APP_PROJECT_ID;
    IF CURR_USER = :APP_USER THEN
      :APP_PROJECT_READ_ONLY := 'NO';
    ELSE
      :APP_PROJECT_READ_ONLY := 'YES';
    END IF;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  NULL;
END;
```

Checking session state shows that `:APP_PROJECT_READ_ONLY`'s value is correct, but it doesn't seem to drive whether `title` is read only:

- If I leave `on_load`'s "page items to return" blank,  then `title` is always editable.
- However if I set it to `title`, then `title` will be always read-only and also it's source control doesn't work,  it's leaved empty (in previous case it was working correctly).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is chronology.
The page renders, conditions evaluated, *then* you calculate your application item on the browser's page load.

Move your code into a computation, perhaps before regions, hence done as part of page render.

REQUEST values are organically only available in page processing, so unless you're explicitly setting that, it may be something to look out for.

You should also consider using declarative actions, where possible.

[www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/05/performance-of-apex-conditions.html](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/05/performance-of-apex-conditions.html)